# Need a xpath : where parent having multiple child, but i required only parent value

Tags: xpath

In below code: parent "div" having three child "span", "script" and "span". but i required the value of Parent "div" which "N/A". "N/A" not comes under any attribute of div. Its just a value of parent "div".

```
<div class="ah-text-align-right ah-font-xsmall" style="">
     <span id="_dcmanageinvestmentsportlet_WAR_ahdcmnginvportlet__FDROR_110hidden" style="display:none">
     <script type="text/javascript">
     <span class="ah-float-left">
N/A 

</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't the xpath `/div` suffice?

Comment: `normalize-space(//div)`

Comment: `//div[text()='N/A']`

Comment: //div[text()='N/A'] is not usefull as we can't hardcode it with N/A, it can any other value also. but normlize-space works for me. thanks a lot for help. as i was stuck on this from long back.

Answer (score 1):

For getting **parent element** you can use double dot `..` after child element xpath.
For getting **text** of an element you can use xpath `text()` function, but depending on implementation of xpath in whatever environment and code you use, it might be unavailable. Note, that text of an element will return actual text node of this element as well as all text nodes of child elements.

For your case if you search a parent of a *span* with *ah-float-left* class, then xpath should be something like following:

```
//span[@class='ah-float-left']/..
```

For getting text of a parent, you'll need following:

```
//span[@class='ah-float-left']/../text()
```

**Note:** looking elements up by class name may return you a collection of elements which in turn will return you collection of parent elements and collection of parent nodes texts, which may not be desired. I would recommend lookup child element by `id`, since xhtml prescribes that elements ids are unique. Thus, an xpath for a parent div should better look like following:

```
//span[@id='_dcmanageinvestmentsportlet_WAR_ahdcmnginvportlet__FDROR_110hidden']/..
```

Comment: //span[@class='ah-float-left']/../text() : This xpath also works as per my requirement. Thnks  eduard. :)